# modifying an existing solenoid to make it less bulky?

Tags: solenoid

I am only familiar with the applications of a solenoid but never designed one. I was given this task of modifying an existing solenoid used in a device to make it less bulkier. I am not understanding where to start from and what are the control and proportionality factors.

construction:
power supply drives a transient suppressor diode (zener) connected in parallel to a solenoid.the solenoid is enclosed in a steel housing that is closed at one end and opened at the other end. solenoid, when energized sufficient enough, attracts a magnetic plate towards itself through the opened end of the housing.once the power supply is turned off, the coil demagnetizes and the plate is expected to go back to its position as earlier.

specifications:

```
outer diameter of the bobbin      = .628 inches
operating voltage                 = 18 to 32 vdc (pick-up voltage = 18vdc max)
wire diameter                     = 41 gauge magnet wire
no of turns                       = 7600 minimum
resistance generated by the coils = 1300 to 1400 
coil outer diameter after wound 
around the bobbin                 = .610 inches max
magnetic holding force            = 2000 to 2500 grams
coil current                      = 25 mA MAX @ 32 VDC
drop out voltage                  = 7 to 8 vdc 
length of the coil                = .530 inches
```

Task: to reduce the size of the solenoid and yet see to that it has the same electrical functionality with same operating values.

my idea: after comparing the existing solenoids in the market i would want to reduce the diameter of the coil & wire and increase the length of the solenoid in a way that the above goal can be achieved. also i understand that the diode is used to ensure that there are no transients in the supply given to the solenoid. i would like to know if we can incorporate any better electronics that are micro sized to perform the same functionality.

but i do not know how to go about it?
kindly help

Comment: you can't reduce the size of an electromagnet without compromising the force using the same electrical power

Comment: @phoebe yes you can do this and you don't have to modify your solenoid. Instead of wasting your time modifying a solenoid spend that few hours and go find a local business (like a tax or pizza place) and offer to hold a sign outside for the hours that it would take you to modify the solenoid (that would break it anyway). Then take the 10$ and go buy a solenoid with the specs that you want from a distributor. Heck you could probably buy 2 or 3.

Comment: "...attracts a magnetic plate towards itself" - sounds like an electromagnet, not a solenoid (which sucks a magnetic rod inside itself). Making an electromagnet longer and thinner may reduce its effectiveness due to the longer magnetic path. Can you show us a photo of the device?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing this is to augment the field using a Nd magnet. However, release might need a reverse current pulse.